# iOS 11 status bar works correctly on PGB but not locally

Tags: xcode, cordova, ios11, statusbar

I have run into a problem with the status bar on iOS 11 when building locally, which seems to be fixed when building through PhoneGapBuild.

When I build my app through PGB the status bar overlays the app correctly, so that the text appears on the dark background and everything is fine (see pic below).

[image: Working Example]

However, when I build on my Mac locally, the app seems to start below the status bar. The bar was originally white, so you could not see any text, but I managed to fix that with cordova-plugin-statusbar. This doesn't resolve my problem completely though, as certain parts of the app now have a black bar at the bottom, so it's only half fixed. This is what the status bar looks like on my local build:

[image: Non-working Example]

I have to build the app store version of the app locally due to some certificate signing that PGB can't do for me, before you ask why I'm doing this locally.

Here is the various version information you might need:

- Ionic - 1.7.16
- Cordova - 6.5.0
- iOS Platform - 4.3.1
- Xcode - 9.1

The build steps consist of just doing `gulp build` and `ionic build ios`, then just leaving everything alone in Xcode and building straight to phone.

Comment: Which version of cordova-plugin-statusbar are you using? (see config.xml for the answer).
I never used PGB but it might be using a different version. There were patches/changes lastly in the plugin code for iOS, because of the new iPhone X.

Same logic for cordova-ios. PGB might be using the last one (or a different one) from yours. You're using 4.3.1. The last one is 4.5.3 (official) and 4.5.4 (npm).



BTW, it's completely off-topic, but I'd recommend using Cordova cli 7+ if you have no specific reason for sticking to 6.5.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was using cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.1.3 and did see various commits on the repo relating to iOS 11 so I updated it to 2.3.0.  

When I look at my PGB portal I can see it is using 4.3.1, which is set by the cordova-cli version that is set for the app.  

EDIT: If I look at the build log of PGB that is still using cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.1.3. I only updated it locally and haven't pushed up the changes.

Comment: Ok, so your statusbar plugin is up to date.
What about this checklist, did you follow it? http://blog.ionicframework.com/ios-11-checklist/

It might be your viewport... Or the fullscreen mode.

Comment: Did not even know this existed. Will read it now and let you know my findings. I did try the viewport thing but I'll start everything fresh and try again.

Comment: Reading through that document is sounds like I will have to upgrade the ionic-angular library to 1.3.5 (currently we are on 1.2.4). My mistake for posting version 1.7.16, this is the version I got when doing ionic --version.  

However, this being production code I will have to do some regression testing and plan another release with the client so holding off doing the upgrade until that's approved.

Comment: I still don't get what PGB are doing differently though, because all the code is the same and they shouldn't be pulling in newer versions of packages to what's specified in config.xml

Comment: You could first check if the issue still happens with ionic 1.3+. Then consider upgrading. Sorry, I can't tell you what PGB is doing differently, I never used the tool. However I think using `viewport-fit=cover` is one important point.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Yes, the viewport setting is important but I think it only works with the 1.3+ version of ionic as adding it in didn't do anything. I think I know the way forward now, just need to get the approval.